# Convergence of function in $L^1$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be bounded and open. Assume that $a: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a Caratheodory function which means $a(x,.,.)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ for almost all $x \in \Omega$ and $a(.,s,\xi)$ is measurable in $\Omega$ for every $(s,\xi) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We  further assume that $$|a(x,s,\xi)| \leq k(x) + \beta(|s|^{p-1}+|\xi|^{p-1})  $$ for almost every $x \in \Omega$, for every $(s,\xi) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and for some $k \in L^{p'}(\Omega), \beta \geq 0, p > 1$ where $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$.

If we consider $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ uniformly, would it then follow that $$a(x,u_{m}, \xi) \rightarrow  a(x,u,\xi) \text{   } \text{  in  } L^{1}(\Omega)$$

Proposed idea:

Does this simply follow by noting that if $$|a(x,u_{m}(x),\xi) - a(x,u(x),\xi)| \rightarrow 0$$ then $$\int_{\Omega}|a(x,u_{m}(x),\xi) - a(x,u(x),\xi)|dx \rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if the convergence is pointwise almost everywhere. Use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with the fact Omega and a are bounded.

The implication for uniform convergence could also follow from the embedding of bounded functions in absolutely integrable functions.

Edit: Hi, as promised I have returned.

You can use the bound

$0 \geq \int_{\Omega} |a(x,u_m(x),\xi) - a(x,u(x),\xi)| dx \leq |\Omega| \sup_{x \in \Omega} |a(x,u_m(x),\xi) - a(x,u(x),\xi)| =: |\Omega| \|u_m - u \|_{L^{\infty}}$

Therefore convergence in $L^{\infty}$ implies convergence in $L^1$ provided $|\Omega| < \infty$ ($| \cdot |$ is the Lebesgue measure in this setting, think area for 'nice' sets).

Arguably you can also use the fact that convergence in $L^{\infty}$ implies convergence pointwise almost everywhere, and use my first comment. Be sure that your assertion is true, your assumptions are very strong for this result. In fact you can strengthen your convergence beyond simply $L^1$ to $L^p$ by using Holders inequality.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Could you expand on what you mean by the second comment.

Comment: I'm on mobile so cannot LaTeX. But use the fact that you can bound the integral by the measure of Omega multiplied by the supremum of the integrand. I can LaTeX tomorrow if you need this.

Comment: if you have a chance could you LATEX the result, I'm not quite getting it, sounds interesting.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: If I have answered your question, could you please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Where do you get the last equation $|\Omega| \sup_{x \in \Omega} |a(x,u_m(x),\xi) - a(x,u(x),\xi)| =: \|u_m - u \|_{L^{\infty}}$ from?

Comment: Also is convergence in $L^{\infty}$ not uniform convergence almost everywhere?

Comment: I have corrected the expression :-) sorry about that (I usually use domains of measure 1). Convergence in $L^{\infty}$ is uniform convergence almost everywhere. It is the uniform convergence of the continuous representatives. (If you equip the space of continuous functions with the $L^{\infty}$ topology then it becomes the topology of uniform convergence)